# processing multiple data files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read multiple files in matlab and extract specific data frome each file, after that the extracted data from each file should be stored in a multiple text files (The number of txt files is the same number of the mat files).

Example: Let say, i have two files FileA.mat and FileB.mat. The data which is extracted from the filaA.mat should be processed and stored in a txt file (FileA.txt). The same process for FileB.mat.

I did the process for one file, but how can i did it for multiple files?

Each file contains multiple data. I need to extract the data inside the variables (RigidBodies.Positions , RigidBodies.Rotations) for the first 290 rows.
The data should be extracted from each file and stored in a separate txt files.

For one file, read the data, process it and then store it in a txt file:

```
load(strcat('Test.mat'));
pos=Test.RigidBodies.Positions(:,:,1:290);
b=Test.RigidBodies.Rotations(:,:,1:290);

for i = 1:290
    c(:,:,i)=reshape(b(:,:,i),3,3);
    rot(:,:,i)=rotm2eul(c(:,:,i));
end

trajdata=[pos,rot]; 
trajdata=reshape(trajdata,6,290)';
a=zeros(290,1);
trajdata=[trajdata,a];
save('data1.mat', 'data');
load('data1.mat')
dlmwrite('test1.txt', data, 'delimiter','\t','newline','pc')
```

These is what i find to read multiple files:

```
mat = dir('*.mat'); 
for q = 1:length(mat) 
load(mat(q).name); 
data(q,:,:) = Testing0006.RigidBodies.Positions(:,:,1:290)
end
```

But how can i change the name of the files inside the for loop?
like:

```
pos=**Test**.RigidBodies.Positions(:,:,1:290);
b=**Test**.RigidBodies.Rotations(:,:,1:290);
```

And how can i put the second loop inside the first one as i did for c and rot in my original code?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question was rolled back to its initial form. If you have a follow-up question, please ask a *new* question rather than repurposing the current one - that way answers stay relevant. Welcome, and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to retrieve the variable using the name of your mat file (if it corresponds to the name of the contained variable, in your example mat(q).name == Testing0006)

```
for q = 1:length(mat) 
    load(mat(q).name);
    [~, testName, ~] = fileparts(mat(q).name);
    testVar = eval(testName); 
    data(q,:,:) = testVar.RigidBodies.Positions(:,:,1:290)
end
```

If you do not need the variable to be in the workspace, you can add a return value to `load(mat(q).name)`

```
for q = 1:length(mat) 
    tmp = load(mat(q).name);
    [~, testName, ~] = fileparts(mat(q).name);
    data(q,:,:) = tmp.(testName).RigidBodies.Positions(:,:,1:290)
end
```

Comment: I faced another issue when i try to build my code for multiple files. I change the description so  can you help me?

Comment: @kamel Please do not change the question after it has been answered. If you have a new question, ask it in a separate post.

Comment: I don't change the question, i used your answer to modify my code. My goal is to make my code processes multiple files and write the results in multiple text files. Your answer is just a part of the solution. Thanks